# Notepad++ - Remove all title attributes on page, at the same time

Tags: notepad++

Within Notepad++ If I have the following HTML on a page...

```
<a href="demo1.htm" title="my first title">demo1</a>
<a href="demo2.htm" title="another title">demo1</a>
<a href="demo3.htm" title="more content">demo1</a>
<a href="demo4.htm" title="additional support for something">demo1</a>
```

....how can I remove all title attributes at the same time, even though they all have different text values?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a search replace with "regular expressions" option on.
Put `title="[^"]+"` in search and nothing in replace, then replace all.

If you don't want an empty space left after deleting the title, put `\stitle="[^"]+"` in search instead.

Answer (score 3):

Find and replace and make sure that the Search Mode is set to "Regular Expression".

Find what : `\stitle=".*"`

Replace with :

Comment: This is amazing.  what does the . and the * mean in detail?

Comment: It means "zero or more of any character".  Take a look at some regular expression tutorials, it is a very useful skill to know.

Answer (score 1):

Replace (Ctrl+H), choose Search Mode -> Regular expression.

Find what:

```
 title=\".*\"
```

(Note the initial blank)

Replace with empty string, replace all.